ValueError: object __array__ method not producing an array when running LSTM in Python
I keep getting the following error when I try to build a LSTM model on a computer:
ValueError: object __array__ method not producing an array

I have looked up common causes for this error and haven't really been able to solve it.\
I have the following tensorflow version: 2.17.0
I have the following numpy: 2.0.0
That version of my tensorflow and numpy packages might be the problem, but I'm not entirely sure. If this is the problem, what versions of these packages should I try?
Here is the code:
# Normalize the data
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
train_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(train)
test_scaled = scaler.transform(test)

# Prepare the data for LSTM
def create_dataset(data, look_back=1):
    X, y = [], []
    for i in range(len(data)-look_back):
        X.append(data[i:(i+look_back), 0])
        y.append(data[i + look_back, 1])
    return np.array(X), np.array(y)

look_back = 5
X_train, y_train = create_dataset(train_scaled, look_back)
X_test, y_test = create_dataset(test_scaled, look_back)

# Reshape input to be [samples, time steps, features]
X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (X_train.shape[0], look_back, 1))
X_test = np.reshape(X_test, (X_test.shape[0], look_back, 1))

# Build the LSTM model
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(50, input_shape=(look_back, 1)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')

